# How do I work with "ASCII art" strings in a program?

Tags: string, go, syntax

I was wondering if adding ASCII Art would make my project better, on top of fixing all of the print statements. I tried to add ASCII Art to my project using backticks but that didn't work.

I tried to add the ASCII given below as the first thing that would be displayed to the user but I was unable to make it work:

```
           _      _        _   
          (_)    | |      | |  
  ___ _ __ _  ___| | _____| |_ 
 / __| '__| |/ __| |/ / _ \ __|
| (__| |  | | (__|   <  __/ |_ 
 \___|_|  |_|\___|_|\_\___|\__|
```

UPDATE: The above issue has been fixed after implementing string literals. However, I am still unable to make ASCII Art such as following work:

```
                      88            88                           
                      ""            88                    ,d     
                                    88                    88     
 ,adPPYba, 8b,dPPYba, 88  ,adPPYba, 88   ,d8  ,adPPYba, MM88MMM  
a8"     "" 88P'   "Y8 88 a8"     "" 88 ,a8"  a8P_____88   88     
8b         88         88 8b         8888[    8PP"""""""   88     
"8a,   ,aa 88         88 "8a,   ,aa 88`"Yba, "8b,   ,aa   88,    
 `"Ybbd8"' 88         88  `"Ybbd8"' 88   `Y8a `"Ybbd8"'   "Y888
```

When I try to convert the above into a string literal, my code doesn't work.

Comment: I have removed all mentions of the project from your question, as they are not relevant to the essence of it, and look too much like self promotion. If that was the latter, please refrain from such actions in the future. If it wasn't, my point still holds true: a question was about working with strings representing what we could call "ASCII art", and this has nothing to do with particulars of the setting you're trying to use them in, and impede understanding of the problem (many people won't read a wall of text).

Comment: Thanks for updating the post! Though my intention was to give as much context as I could give so that people would understand the issue more, I will try to keep things concise and to the point from now on.

Comment: See ["How to create a MCVE"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is linked to in the ["landing" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about what you can and cannot do on SO ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [raw string literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals):

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines.

```golang
asciiArt := `           _      _        _   
          (_)    | |      | |  
  ___ _ __ _  ___| | _____| |_ 
 / __| '__| |/ __| |/ / _ \ __|
| (__| |  | | (__|   <  __/ |_ 
 \___|_|  |_|\___|_|\_\___|\__|`

fmt.Println(asciiArt).
```

You could apply these raw string literals at various points of your code to avoid repeated calls to `fmt.Println()`.

Comment: It works! But there are still some ASCII Art which are not working. Please see the updated post again, I have given a few examples...

Comment: I think the issue now is that the ASCII art you are trying to store in a backtick delimited string contains backticks. In that case, you can concatenate string literals using the `+` operator.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I will check out the + operator and revert back if somehow that doesn't work for me.